# Picture Refresh without reload whole page doesn't work in IE version9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">


<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://www.kitco.com/images/live/gold.gif" width="90%" height="100%">


<script>
  setInterval(function() {
     var images = document.images;
     for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
        images[i].src = images[i].src.replace(/\btime=[^&]*/, 'time=' + new      Date().getTime());
      }
  }, 1000); // 10000 milliseconds = 10 seconds
  </script>
```

This is the code, it works well in Chrome however it cannot work in IE version9, I am a newbie in programming, can someone help me solve it? Or give any comment about how should I solve it?

Comment: You need to remove one of those doctype declarations. Also, please edit your question and it's title to describe the actual problem you're having.

Comment: `it cannot work` what do you mean by not working?

Comment: Can you say which version(s) of IE it is not working with (IE6 to IE11 cover a huge range); also describe the problem you see and the expected behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, i am newbie in the forum as well
it cannot refresh in the IE version 9 browser, but it can work in the chrome. so what should i do in this problem.

Comment: @NewBie_PleaseHelp You have a meta tag saying you want IE9 to behave like IE7. If you remove that does it start working in IE9? (I'm assuming you have already sorted out the double doctype problem.)

Comment: @DarrenCook, i already go for other ways to do this, it also can get the result that i want, i using 1 master page that embed several page into several iframe, and it auto refresh on the subHtml page instead of refresh the masterPage, so it solve. thx all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As suggested by [HTML 4.01], to include images, authors may use the OBJECT element or the IMG element. Therefore, **it is recommended not to use this attribute to find the images in the document but getElementsByTagName** with HTML 4.01 or getElementsByTagNameNS with XHTML 1.0.

[source](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-90379117)

So, please replace your code by the next ; [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName)

```
setInterval(function() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); // get all img DOM objects
    for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
        images[i].src = images[i].src.replace(/\btime=[^&]*/, 'time=' + new Date().getTime());
    }
}, 1000); // 10000 milliseconds = 10 seconds
```

Also, please declare one DOCTYPE, not two.

Comment: Firstly, thx for your answer. The result still the same, it work in chrome but cannot work in IE version 9